# Проблема с SourceMapDevToolPlugin webpack 5 в режиме development

Tags: javascript, webpack

Ковыряю сейчас webpack 5 и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

При сборке в режиме `production` (`webpack --mode=production`) все работает замечательно сборка идет отлично, но вот в режиме `development` (`webpack --mode=development --watch`) получаю такую ошибку:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (C:\openserver\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:112:10)
    at SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.apply (C:\openserver\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.js:50:27)
    at C:\openserver\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:160:53
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:100:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:993:26)
    at C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1035:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\OpenServer\domains\test.js\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1030:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-webpack-project@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-webpack-project@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-18T20_43_45_589Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Как видно, проблема в плагине SourceMapDevToolPlugin (если его отключить, ошибки не будет).

Но тогда непонятно, почему все работает в режиме `production`?

Вот файл `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

const context = path.resolve(__dirname);

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        main: [
            './js/index.js',
            './css/index.scss',
        ],
        docx: './css/docx.scss'
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "/prod/",
        path: context + "/prod",
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        chunkFilename: "chunks/chunk.[id].js",
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            extractComments: false,
        })],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            "@babel/preset-react",
                        ],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {sourceMap: true,},
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {sourceMap: true,},
                    },
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/i,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            }


        ],
    },

    plugins: [

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].min.css',
        }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: "maps/[file].map"
        }),


        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: 'http://test.js',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            files: [context + '/**/*', './../**/*'],
            notify: false,
            reload: true,          
        }),
    ],
};
```

В документации https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/#basic-use-case `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` написано:

> Tip
> If you want to use a custom configuration for this plugin in development mode, make sure to disable the default one. I.e. set devtool: false.

Пробовал, ставил `devtool: false`, ничего...

**Если кто знает в чем проблема, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!**

Answer (score 1):

Короче говоря, дело в кешировании.

Я работал в PhpStorm, удалил папку .idea и все заработало. Вот так.